# Windows 8 found NFC but ProximityDevice.GetDefault() return "null"

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Windows 8 find the NFC and i see toggle button on the setting page.

I try to use the Metro app sample of Proximity http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731 C#, but method ProximityDevice.GetDefault() return "null".

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: did you declare the capabilities for Proximity?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm trying to run an app on Windows 8.1 and I want it to detect my Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Apparently, the Surface Pro device does not support this. Based on: http://surfaceadvice.com/cant-live-with-em-cant-live-without-em-nfc-and-gps/